# Assigning and reading multidimensional arrays in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I'm stumped.

```
for a in range(0,500): #500 is a highly variable number but using it for example purposes
    b = findall(r'<(.*?)>', d) # d will return a highly number variable number of matches could be anywhere from 45-10000
    c.append([b])
print(c[0][1])
```

This returns the error because everything from 'b' goes into c[0][0].  I can understand this.  The question is how do I split 'b' apart so I can put it into c so I can

```
print(c[0][234])
```

and get it give me back the 235, err element 234 of the 1, err 0, line?

This is a situation like I said above where the number of times going through 'b' will be variable, at least for right now until I get the entire file prepped I can only that 'b' in the end will be way north of 10,000 and probably closer to 100,000 by the time I have all the data collection finished.  The number of elements that are stored can and  will be highly variable depending on the file that they come from.  They are all coming from a csv file but I'm hoping to not to deal with adding in any 'complexity' by going out and having to deal with the csv module...since I've never used it before and that will probably just lead to more questions.

I have tried something similiar to...different variables naturally so things would be appropriately matched up

```
d = list(zip(*(e.split(',') for e in b)))
```

all this has did is split on each and every letter versus on the comma.

Comment: "everything from 'b' goes into c[0][0]" - first, no it doesn't. Second, why are you appending `[b]` instead of `b`?

Comment: You win.  I had seen it done that way in other questions/answers that I was looking at trying to get an answer before asking the question here.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is coming from the square brackets you have in `c.append([b])`. The brackets create an extra list that contains the list `b`. So rather than a two dimensional data structure, you're ending up with three dimensions. Your indexing fails because `c[0][1]` is trying to get a second value from the middle list (which only ever has one item in it).

You might get what you want with `c[0][0][1]` instead. But you probably don't actually want that extra level in your data structure. You can avoid creating it by using: `c.append(b)`